# Azure SQL Managed instance latency to read replica

Tags: metrics, latency, azure-sql-managed-instance

We are using Business Critical service tier for Azure Managed Instance and we are leveraging the read-only replicas heavily.  How can I get some visibility into the latency between the read/write replica and the read replica?

Ultimately I would like to alert if that falls behind.

Thank you,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will have much visibility in the latency. The BC tier have SSDs and their latency according to my knowledge is less than 5 seconds.

In the BC tier, there are always two secondary nodes running on the backend using Always on AGs.

Here are some DMV queries when you connect to read-only replica

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/read-scale-out#monitoring-and-troubleshooting-read-only-replicas

hopefully this helps